# How to organize orders in table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am new in the world of Excel so please advise.
I have a table like this, the vertical axis is a date, and the horizontal axis is the order numbers and the number of items in each. Orders have different prefixes like e111, eb111, r111, and so on depending on the type of purchase
I want to know if any of the points below are possible to implement here.

1. Show at the bottom of the page the biggest (laters number of each order prefixes from the whole document, or at least this page).
2. Count numbers of orders with different prefixes (example: e = 22 pieces, eb5 = prices, r = 10 pieces and so on)
3. Count the number of orders and pieces by the background color (green, purple, and so on, or any other separation method I can imply without adding an additional row)
4. Assign the price for each item and multiply the number of pieces by price separately for orders marked with green and purple colors

I would be grateful for any advice, thank you!
[image]

Comment: 3 & 4 would be impossible without VBA code.  Formula won't recognise the colour of a cell.  1 & 2 would be much easier with a different layout - 1 column for date (repeated for each order on that day), 1 column for order type (e, eb, etc), 1 column for order number (423, 424, etc), and a final column for the Pcs quantity.

Comment: With layout I mentioned in above comment you can then use `UNIQUE` to get a list of all order types, then `MAXIFS` to get the maximum order number per date & order type, `COUNTIFS` for count of orders per date and order type.